# Shell pipes - the order of things

Tags: bash, shell, netcat, named-pipe, fifo

Because `netcat` on my box doesn't support `-e`,
The `netcat` man page gives me this workaround:

```
$ rm -f /tmp/f; mkfifo /tmp/f
$ cat /tmp/f | /bin/sh -i 2>&1 | nc -l 127.0.0.1 1234 > /tmp/f
```

I don't understand how this works.
I though that when you try to `cat /tmp/f` that that would block until something is written to `/tmp/f` and if that's blocked how does the rest of the command run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All commands in a pipeline are **started simultaneously** and run simultaneously – command 2 does not wait for command 1 to exit. Instead, pipelines rely on read operations blocking until the preceding command has produced some output.

For example, the output (stdout) of `cat /tmp/f` is directly<sup>1</sup> connected to the input of `/bin/sh -i`; whenever *sh* tries to read from its stdin, it will block until *cat* has produced some output.

---

<sup>1</sup> (Almost directly; cat's stdout and sh's stdin are tied to two ends of a 'pipe' object.)

Comment: Wow, the more I learn bash/shell, the more it impresses me. Thank you.